# Eigenvalues of operator with strange commutator

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given an operator of the form $A+B$, where $A$ and $B$ have the following commutator
$$[A,B]=\lambda (A+B)$$

Where $\lambda$ is some real number. Is there anything that can be said about the eigenvalues of the operator $A+B$?

It's clear that $A+B$ raises and lowers the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (depending on the sign of $\lambda$). I'm curious however about the spectrum of $A+B$.

If it is important, both $A$ and $B$ have real elements but are not symmetric. And $A+B$ is tridiagonal. Those properties are specific to the problem I am considering, but I'd be interested to see what the above commutator can say if anything about its eigenvalues.

**Edit**

For illustrative purposes, the example I found which inspired this question is with the following definitions of infinite dimensional matrices.

$$A_{nm}=-\lambda n(\delta_{nm}+\delta_{n,m+1})$$
$$B_{nm}=(-\lambda n+\alpha)(\delta_{nm}+\delta_{n,m-1})$$

These operators satisfy the above commutator for any $\alpha$.

Note that $\text{tr}(A+B)$ is divergent.

While I have an explicit solution to the commutator, I know nothing about the eigenvalues.

Comment: So you still use $[A,B]=AB-BA$, the commutator? Which commutator is strange?

Comment: Yes it is the usual commutator. I meant it was strange because of the right hand side. The word strange is a bit subjective, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commutator implies the following similarity transformation

$$e^{cA}(A+B)e^{-cA}=e^{c\lambda}(A+B)$$

for any constant $c$. Because this is a similarity transformation, $A+B$ and $e^{c\lambda}(A+B)$ have the same eigenvalues. If $\lambda\neq 0$, this means that either $A+B=0$, like @Dietrich Burde pointed out, or $A+B$ has a continuum of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

We can say something about the eigenvalues of $A+B$, namely that they must sum up to zero. This follows from the fact that
$$
\operatorname{tr}([A,B])=\operatorname{tr}(AB-BA)=0,
$$
so that, for $\lambda\neq 0$, we obtain  $\operatorname{tr}(A+B)=0$. Recall that we have given the matrix equation
$$
AB-BA=\lambda(A+B).
$$
Obvious solutions are given by $B=-A$ (I always assume that $A,B\in M_n(K)$).

Comment: What about when these are infinite dimensional matrices? The trace is not necessarily defined. I will edit my question with an explicit example where this occurs.

Comment: Then the trace is replaced by $\sum_k<Ae_k,e_k>$, where $\{e_k\}$ is any orthonormal basis.

Comment: I think the question wasn't so much what the definition of the trace is, as what to do in case the commutator is not of trace class.