# Infinite dimensional matrix on countable basis vector space having uncountable eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, infinite-matrices

In my last question on this site ([eigenvalues of operator with strange commutator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3792967/eigenvalues-of-operator-with-strange-commutator/3793034#3793034)), I found a matrix $A+B$ with the commutator

$$[A,B]=\lambda (A+B)$$

Where $A_{nm}=kn(\delta_{nm}+\delta_{n,m+1})$ and $B_{nm}=(kn-\lambda)(\delta_{nm}+\delta_{n,m-1})$ for any constant $k$, and $n,m\in\mathbb N$. This commutator can be used to show that if $\lambda$ and $A+B$ are nonzero, then $A+B$ must have a continuum of eigenvalues (either half or the entire real number line). I proved this in an answer to my own question linked above.

Because of how it is defined, $A+B$ acts on a vector space with a countable basis, but somehow it has an uncountable number of eigenvalues. How is this possible?

Comment: One broad example of such matrices are the so-called 'compact matrices'. There are too many questions. The third question is too broad for an answer. You might want to focus the question a bit.

Comment: I removed the last question.

Comment: What do you mean by "$A+B$ has a discrete basis"? How can an operator have a basis?

Comment: I meant the vector space it acts on has a discrete basis, I will edit my question accordingly.